# Parsing string as int with "Model.x" property in for loop remains in string format

Tags: c#, string, model, int

I have a simple form that accepts a number from a radio button selection (1-5) of 11 questions and posts the values into a database as varchar(10) data. I intend to send the user to a result page that lists the sum of these scores through a simple for loop, but when I try parsing the data to integer format, it simply results in zero due to error parsing. Here's an example of my code:

```
// Q1 - Q11 are the questions in my Db, using Model property

       int sum = 0;
       int temp = 0;
       String question;

         for (int i = 11; i >= 1; i--)
         {
           question = "Model.Q" + i.ToString();
           temp = int.Parse(question);
           sum += temp;                          
         }

       return sum;
```

What's strange is that if I parse them individually, such as writing:
         `Int32.TryParse(Model.Q5, out temp);` 
I am able to parse the data just fine. My console shows that the loop keeps the `question` variable as `"Model.Qx"` with quotations, ultimately resulting in `0` for the sum. I have also tried using `Int32.TryParse();` for that as well and it resulted in no difference, besides handling the error.

Can a string simply not be parsed if it contains punctuation in concatenation with the `i` variable, or am I missing something else here? I want to avoid parsing each question individually, as it looks rather ugly in code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: return statement should be outside of for loop

Comment: If you post the definition of Q5 from your Model, I can suggest a better way to do it.

Comment: @apomene My bad, it was originally outside of the loop and I must have accidentally placed it in there while writing this question. Fixing that now!

Comment: @RobinBennett Q5 or any of the Q's would be a number 1-5 (depending on user radio button selection) in varchar(10) format in my Model.

Comment: OK, I've added a section to my answer - does it help?

Comment: @RobinBennett Yes, thank you! This seems like a good workaround to my issue. I appreciate the explanation, it certainly makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that you're trying to access a variable by using a string with the same name. This won't work, in the same way that the name `gitgecko` is not *you*.

If your model has got a number of properties with similar names, you could write a function to switch between them:

```
object GetQ(int number)
{
    switch(number)
    { 
        case 1: return Model.Q1;
        case 2: return Model.Q2;
        // etc...
     }      
}
```

Or you could change your model to store these variables in an array or list, or whatever is appropriate.

For example, if you've currently got:

```
class Model
{
    string Q1;
    string Q2:
    // repeated 11 times
```

You could have:

```
class Model
{
    string[] Q = new string[11];
}
```

which gives you the ability to do `Model.Q[x]`